# Add multiple rows dynamically in jQuery DataTables(with FIDDLE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to add new rows on cell click using `DataTables` API.

Currently, I am able to add the row for the first time. But from second time on-wards, it is acting a bit weird. I was able to create this example for any of you to give it a shot.

After much work throughout the day, this is what I could accomplish.

[EXAMPLE TO WORK UPON](http://live.datatables.net/buciqaye/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing indexing manually is not the best idea considering that Datatables does this internally anyway.

Here's the official how-to for the index column: https://datatables.net/examples/api/counter_columns.html

The only problem here is that `row.add()` can only *append* a row (i.e. can't insert into arbitrary position). To overcome this you can retrieve the internal table data, modify it and put it back again. E.g.

```
var newRowData = [
    "",
    'New Name',
    'New Position',
    'New Office',
    26,
    'New Date',
    'New Salary'];

tableApi.row.add(newRowData);

var data = datatable.fnGetData(); // get data
datatable.fnClearTable(false); // erase the data in the table

data.splice(currentRowIndex + 1, 0, data.pop());  // move the row of interest into desired position

datatable.fnAddData(data); // put data back
```

Full example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dekkard/0oufp7sr/)

Comment: I'm not sure I get it. Do you want to add a row and then remove it on the same click?

Comment: yes exactly...more like the row detail feature....but then by doing it this way...the newly added rows will look like as it was part of the original table

Comment: i appreciate your approach to add new rows +1

Comment: I still don't quite understand what you want to achieve. If you create a row and immediately delete it you won't see it at all.

Comment: @dekkard...it is more like child row feature..kind of a toggle option

Comment: Are you talking about **collapsing** the row?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78103/discussion-between-user2281858-and-dekkard).

Answer (score 1):

That code of yours is somewhat off a mess. Here are some of the problems:

- The `AddNewRows()` function is called by an `onclick` event in the html of the `td` (but not for all rows?). This also means is does not work with the newly added rows.
- In the `AddNewRows()` function you use alot of `$('#example').DataTable()` instead of (re-)using the variable `table`.
- In each new call to `AddNewRows()` you add a jQuery `click` event to all rows of the table (before adding the new row, so the event is not bound for the new row). After the e.g. fifth call to the function all rows have five events bound and so there are two times five alerts ...
- The `AddNewRows` function is called with an `onclick` event on the `td` and after the function finished the click event propagates to the `tr` and the newly bound event for the `tr` is immediately called (plus all the events from previous calls, see previous point). Why not just use one event? Also the newly added event on the `tr` also works for click on other `td`s then the one which original hat the call to `AddNewRows()`.

Try to simplify your code, maybe even build it up from scratch so that it only does what it is supposed to do. After that, come back here if you have still problems left.